# Loop through range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

The code aims to loop through all cells in a specified range. Below is a part of the code. It seems like there is an error with using `Rng` in the for loop. When `Rng` is replaced with a specified range e.g. `Range("A1:B20")`, it works, but the code breaks at

```
Cells(cell2.Row, LastCol1 + 1) = Application.VLookup(Range("A2:A1000"), strFileToOpen.Range("A10:C10000"), 3)
```

```
   Dim Rng, cell, cell1, cell2 As Range
   Dim strFileToOpen As Variant

    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose the File", _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")


    If strFileToOpen = False Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen
    End If

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Rng = Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
            
            
            For Each cell2 In Rng
                If Trim(cell2.Value) <> "" Then
                    Cells(cell2.Row, LastCol1 + 1) = Application.VLookup(Range("A2:A1000"), strFileToOpen.Range("A10:C10000"), 3)
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `Dim Rng, cell, cell1, cell2 As Range` only declares `cell2 As Range` but `Rng, cell, cell1` as `Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable otherwise it is `Variant` by default:

```
Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
```

Furthermore `Rng` is an `Object` and therefore has to use `Set`

```
Set Rng = Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
```

Finally make sure you use `Option Explicit` because your variables `LastCol1` and `LastCol` are not defined and therefore considered as `0` but column `0` does not exist counting starts with `1`.

Make sure you use meaningful variable names. Names like `cell`, `cell1`, `cell2` are a nightmare for every programmer. Whenever you fell you need to number variable names you can be sure you are doing it wrong.

Finally your variable `strFileToOpen` is only a path to a file because `Application.GetOpenFilename` only returns a `String`. And a `String` does not have a `Range` so `strFileToOpen.Range("A10:C10000")` cannot work.

Therefore you need to do something like

```
Dim OpenedWorkbook As Workbook
Set OpenedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileToOpen)
```

and use

```
OpenedWorkbook.Worksheets("SpecifySheetName").Range("A10:C10000")
```

So something like the following

```
Dim strFileToOpen As Variant
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                Title:="Please choose the File", _
                FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

If strFileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim OpenedWorkbook As Workbook
    Set OpenedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileToOpen)
End If

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName") 'or ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet if the sheet name is not defined

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim WorkingRange As Range
Set WorkingRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, 2), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)) 'LastCol is not defined!
        
Dim Cell As Range        
For Each Cell In WorkingRange 
    If Trim(Cell.Value) <> vbNullString Then
        'LastCol is not defined!
        ws.Cells(Cell.Row, LastCol1 + 1) = Application.VLookup(ws.Range("A2:A1000"), OpenedWorkbook.Worksheet("DefineWorksheetName").Range("A10:C10000"), 3)
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: the last column variables are actually defined, but only included relevant parts of the code to keep the code short. after specifying the type for every variable like above, there is still an error like mentioned in the question above. it breaks at the vlookup line.

Comment: @appleorange Please have a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the question . please let me know if there's a more efficient way to write below

```
Cells(cellrng.Row, LastCol1 + 1).Formula = Application.VLookup(Cells(cellrng.Row, 1).Value, Workbooks("FileName.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10000"), 3, False)
```